# SQL запрос. Вроде простая задача, но не получается

Tags: mysql, order-by

Прошу помощи с формированием запроса MySQL запроса. Битый час бьюсь, но не получается (

Две таблицы:

1. post

-id

-title

2. post_status:

-id

-post_id = id из первой таблицы post

-post_status_id

-date_at

нужно: выбрать все записи из таблицы post, у которых на конкретную дату был статус из списка
соответственно, в параметры запроса приходит дата и массив допустимых статусов.
На выходе - записи из таблицы post.
Думал сделать так:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_status_id WHERE status_id IN (1,2) AND date_at < "2023-05-01 00:00:00" GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC);
```

но уже во вложенном запросе `(SELECT post_id FROM post_status_id WHERE status_id IN (1,2) AND date_at < "2023-05-01 00:00:00" GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC)` получаю ошибку:
#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'base.post_status.post_status_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

#1055 - Выражение #2 списка SELECT отсутствует в предложении GROUP BY и содержит неагрегированный столбец 'base.post_status.post_status_id', который функционально не зависит от столбцов в предложении GROUP BY; это несовместимо с sql_mode=only_full_group_by
Хочется написать правильный запрос без отключения only_full_group_by. Это ведь явно возможно )...

Comment: Зачем вам в запросе `GROUP BY post_id`? Уберите его и все должно заработать. Да и order by из вложенного запроса надо убрать

Comment: так если я уберу группировку по post_id, то я не получу уникальных (в части постов на дату) значений, статус которые хочу сравнить с искомым статусом

Comment: Если в IN() какой то id будет более одного раза, то запись из основной таблицы к которой собственно IN применяется будет все равно одна. уникальность внутри IN не имеет значения. И ок, пусть будет group by. но если вы группируете по post_id то как вы при этом собрались сортировать по полю id, его же нет в группировке. Ну и плюс к этому order by внутри IN вообще не имеет смысла ибо на порядок результата он никак не повлияет

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особое внимание пунктам 5 и 3.

Answer (score 0):

ну вроде получилось )

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id
 FROM post_status
 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM post_status WHERE date_at<"2023-05-10 04:00:00" GROUP BY post_id) AND status_id IN (1,2))
```

Comment: `AND status_id IN (1,2)` лучше внести внутрь `select max` запроса. Иначе может получиться, что максимальный ИД будет взят для статуса, который не нужен, и тогда `id IN` будет `false`

Comment: Ох, не нравится мне это решение... уж больно много ограничений должно быть в схеме, чтобы это решение было верным.

Comment: Akina, а чем решение не нравится? Пока не понимаю о каких ограничениях идет речь (